# How to upload folders/files from Git repositories to S3 bucket with Terraform?

Tags: bash, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

The main concern is how to create mapping to those folders since, folders and terraform modules are in different repositories.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object "upload" {
  bucket = "bucketname"
  key = "how_to_procede"
  source = "how_to_procede"
```

}

Comment: You have to provide more details and some example of what exactly you want to do, and what is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the [GitHub Terraform provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs) does not provide any data sources for getting a list of files in a repository or for retrieving individual files.

Therefore, if the repository is private, the only feasible way to do this is to clone the repository to the machine where Terraform is running, then use the [fileset](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/fileset.html) function to get a list of files in the repository, then use that list in a `for_each` on the `aws_s3_bucket_object` resource to upload each file. You'll need to do the cloning in an external shell command; you can use a module such as [this one](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Invicton-Labs/shell-resource/external/latest) to accomplish that.

If the repository is public, and you know ahead of time which files you want to send to S3, then you can use the [HTTP provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/http/latest/docs/data-sources/http) to download the file from its GitHub URL, parse the response body to extract the file contents, and then specify those contents in the `content` field of the `aws_s3_bucket_object` resource.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. This is what we finally implemented.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If the issue is resolved, you can accept the answer to mark the question as closed. Also, a warning note: careful with using the `aws_s3_bucket_object` resource if there are a lot (more than a couple hundred) files in the repository. Terraform will refresh the state of each one individually, which can drastically slow down the plan/apply. Consider using the same module I suggested to use `s3 sync` from the AWS CLI via the shell.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Good to know for future if number of files will increase.

Answer (score 1):

Since [October 2021](https://github.com/integrations/terraform-provider-github/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#4160-oct-5-2021) the GitHub Terraform provider has the data source [github_repository_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/integrations/github/latest/docs/data-sources/repository_file). This data source allows you to read files within a GitHub repository. You can then upload your file to S3 using the [aws_s3_object](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_object) resource from the Terraform AWS provider.

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "ABC123"
  secret_key = "dEf456"
}
 
provider "github" {
  token = "xyz890"
  owner = "some-owner"
}
 
data "github_repository_file" "my_file" {
  provider   = github
  repository = "my-repository"
  file       = "my_file.py"
}
 
resource "aws_s3_object" "my_file_on_s3" {
  bucket  = "my-bucket"
  key     = "my_filename_on_s3"
  content = data.github_repository_file.my_file.content
}
```