# Using Terraform to copy website files/folders from GitHub repo to AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to figure out a way to copy all files/folders from a GitHub repro to an AWS S3 bucket using Terraform.

I came across the github_repository_file data source, but I believe it is limited to a single file vs multiple files and directories.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68505552/13126651 check this

Comment: Thank you @JatinMehrotra - the issue is that the github_repository_file data source is limited to only one file, I am not able to find way to list all the files within a repo.